# Edgelist from a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, networkx

I'd like to make a pretty plot of my binary tree.

Here's my custom BinaryTree class:

```
class BinaryTree():

   def __init__(self, data):
      self.data = data
      self.right = None
      self.left = None
```

Now, in order to plot this graph I'll use the networkx library and so I need to convert my graph to a networkx object and then plot it using graphviz. The problem is the **edge list**: in order to build my new object, I need the edges.

For example given a binary tree like in the following figure.
[image]

I need to retrieve the edge list. Would be something like this:

```
[(0,1),(0,2),(2,3),(2,4)]
```

Notice that in my case I don't have id on node. And so how can I do this?
I believe it might be some recursive function taking account on the depth but I'm having some difficulties so a little help is appreciated. ;)

EDIT

Thanks for the answers. But I found a solution by myself that works well..:P
Here it is:

```
def edgelist(node, output, id=0):

    if node is None or isinstance(node, bt.Leaf):
         return output

    if node.left:
         output.append((id, id*2+1))

    if node.right:
         output.append((id, id*2+2))

    edgelist(node.left, output, id*2+1)
    edgelist(node.right, output, id*2+2)

    return output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could modify the `BinaryTree` class to dump an edgelist:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools as IT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class BinaryTree(object):
   def __init__(self, data):
      self.data = data
      self.right = None
      self.left = None
      self.name = None
   def edgelist(self, counter = IT.count().next):
       self.name = counter() if self.name is None else self.name
       for node in (self.left, self.right):       
           if node:
               node.name = counter() if node.name is None else node.name
               yield (self.name, node.name)
       for node in (self.left, self.right):
           if node:
               for n in node.edgelist(counter):
                   yield n

tree = [BinaryTree(i) for i in range(5)]        
tree[0].left = tree[1]
tree[0].right = tree[2]
tree[2].left = tree[3]
tree[2].right = tree[4]

edgelist = list(tree[0].edgelist())
print(edgelist)   

G = nx.Graph(edgelist)
nx.draw_spectral(G)
plt.show()
```

yields

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`collections.dequeue`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to avoid recursion:

```
import collections
def edges_breadth(tree):
    history = collections.deque([tree])
    while history:
        parent = history.popleft()
        for c in (parent.left, parent.right):
            if c:
                yield((parent.data, c.data))
                history.append(c)
```

Note that this is a breadth-first traversal. You may want another [traversal order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), namely a depth-first one like in this pre-order recursive implementation:

```
def edges_depth(tree):
    results = []
    def visit(parent, child):
        if child:
            results.append((parent, child))
            visit(child.left)
            visit(child.right)
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def edgelist(T):
    results = []
    def visit(parent,child):
        if child:
            if parent != None:results.append((parent.key, child.key))
            visit(child,child.left)
            visit(child,child.right)
        return results
  return visit(None,T.root)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.